# Django, How to update the DateTimeField() of model by the view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

As mentioned in the title, I have a model containing the `DateTimeField()`

**models.py**

```
class DataRow(models.Model):
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

I would like to update this field every time I call the model in view. I tried to do it as follows:

**views.py**

```
data_row = get_object_or_404(DataRow, pk=row_id)
data_row.last_edit_date = datetime.now()
data_row.save()
```

I also checked the `auto_add=True` attribute and calling the `.save()` method of model, but it did not work either.

Comment: If you want the timestamp to be updated every time the model is saved, set [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) to `True`. If you don't use that option, then calling  `data_row.last_edit_date = datetime.now()` then `data_row.save()` should work in an individual view - you'll have to provide more information about how to reproduce the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Note that `default=datetime.now()` is a mistake. If you want to specify a default instead of using `auto_now` then use the callable `default=datetime.now`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It throws an error?

Comment: Add some print/log to confirm if the view code you have is actually being executed.

Comment: Problem has been solved. In fact, the way using `auto_add=True` worked. The problem was not updating the display of data from the last_edit_date field in the view template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is in the comments above.